# float variables initialization java

Tags: java

The following code snippet gave me compiler error at Line 1.

```
public abstract class xyz
{

    float Gamma = 20.0; //Line 1
    public class Alpha
    {
        void Beta()
        {
            System.out.println("this is atest");
        }
    }
}



abc0.java:5: error: possible loss of precision
        float density = 20.0;
                        ^
  required: float
  found:    double
2 errors
```

As per my understanding, float is used for decimal variables.

Am I missing something obvious or should I have to always use casting for decimal variables initialization ?

EDIT : I know 'f' can be used at the end for float variables but is it MANDATORY ?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Floating-point literals are considered `double`s unless you specify that they're just `float`s. (Similarly, integer literals are `int`s unless specified otherwise.) Append the letter `f` to the number to make it a `float`:

```
float density = 20.0f;
```

The JLS has [comprehensive typing rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) for literal values. No, you don't have to make the literal a `float` with `f`, but then you have to cast it with `(float)` if you want to fit it in a `float` variable, since Java won't automatically try to shove a number of one type into a variable with a smaller range.

Comment: Should just use doubles IMO, float hasn't been used much in years.

Comment: @redFive I largely agree with you, use doubles unless there are large arrays and memory is an issue.  But, my understanding is the the GPU chips mainly use floats, so they may be making a comeback.

Comment: @redFIVE Also, for code that's going to be running on 32-bit processors (most ARMs), single-precision can be much faster.

Comment: Machine Learning libraries (TensorFlow, etc) require `floats`.

Answer (score 3):

should be

```
float density = 20.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

float density = 20.0f;

If you try to assign a decimal number you must place an "f" at the end, otherwise Java will assume you are trying to assign a double .A  double would more precisely cover more numbers that you could type in.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [JLS, §3.10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2), all floating point literals are interepreted as `double` unless specified as a `float`.

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d (§4.2.3).

Change your declaration to:

```
float density = 20.0f;
```

In general, consider why you're using `float` - it has less precision than `double`, and isn't used nearly as often.

Answer (score 1):

> As per my understanding, float is used for decimal variables.

No. Numerical literals with fraction parts are treated as doubles by default.

Answer (score 1):

In Java by default decimal values are stored as double. But for storing it as a floating  point number we explicitly need to declare, like

float varName = 10.0f; or  float varName = (float)10.0;